# Does OS suspend a thread that is blocked on IO

Tags: io, operating-system, blocking, suspend

So when a thread does an expensive IO operation I understand that it is blocked (will not process any more instructions until IO is complete). What I was wondering is if the OS is optimized to actually suspend that thread and not schedule it until that IO operation is complete.

So essentially the question is does a thread blocked on IO continue to take up CPU cycles doing nothing, or does the OS suspend it and wake it back up when it is ready?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I imagine all modern day OS would behave the same on such a fundamental matter, no?

Comment: I don't know. In Linux, I/O on pipes and fifos blocks if you attempt to read from an empty pipe.

Comment: I am more wondering if it suspends? I get that it blocks but is it still scheduled or is the thread suspended and notified by the OS when something is available on the queue. As in is the thread that is blocked still taking up CPU cycles

Comment: Blocked mean no waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: Ah okay. It seems we just have a difference in terminology. From what I've learned if a thread is blocked it just means it is not executing further instructions because it is busy processing the current one. Meaning a CPU intensive function call blocks but clearly CPU cycles are still being used. A suspended thread is one that doesn't get scheduled

Answer (score 2):

> So essentially the question is does a thread blocked on IO continue to take up CPU cycles doing nothing, or does the OS suspend it and wake it back up when it is ready?

Typically when a task is blocked (waiting for IO, or time, or mutex, or ...) the scheduler is told to find something else to do and either switches to another task (if there is one) or puts the CPU into some kind of power saving state (if there are no other tasks); and scheduler won't give the task any CPU time until it is unblocked (until whatever it was waiting for happened) or something abnormal happens (e.g. `signal` that cancels the IO).

The only case I've seen that's different is single-tasking operating systems that don't have a scheduler. In this case there's no "blocked" state and often the only task just busy waits.